# How to make a TF vector?

Tags: python-3.x, vector, nlp

I want to make a TF vector for a word sense disambiguation project. I have some files, each for an ambiguated word which contains a Persian sentence, a tab and then an English word (which shows the sense of the ambiguated word) in each line. I extracted the 1000 most frequent words of the file and I have to make a TF vector according to this words. (The TF formula is: ,=log(1+,)). So the output should be a file which has 1000 columns of numbers and a column for the English word. (1001 columns).

For that, first I omitted stop words and punctuation. Then I wrote a function to extract 1000 most frequent words. Then a function to calculate each word's frequency in the file and then I claculated ,=log(1+,). (, is each word's frequency in the file), and put the result in a dictionary ("TFvauesl" in the code). The problem is the TF function in the code.

1) for example if my file has 10 lines, it should return 10 lines in the output, too . But the code returns more than 10 lines. How should I correct it?

2) To make the TF vector I have to say if the word in each line of the file (which I put them in the witouStops list), is in the most frequent words and also is in the TFvalues dictionary, instead of that word, it puts its value which is in TFvalues dictionary. The TF function which I wrote doesn't return correct answer. How can I change it?

3) As I said before, the output file should have 1000 columns of numbers and a column for the English word. my data file has some sentences in each line. They have between 5 to 9 words (more or less). for the words in each line, which are in the most frequent words, the code should put its TF value which is in TFvalues dictionary. Now the question is, for the rest of that 1000 most frequent words which are not in the lines, should I write "0"? Is this the way we make TF vector? hint: I want to use weka for classifying, so the number of each line should be equall. All of them should have 1001 columns.

An example of a binary arff file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ltepz1rk3ia9md/golTest.arff?dl=0

data file example:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f4z8neslw3ht9e8/golTest.txt?dl=0

```
from hazm import*
from collections import Counter
import collections
import math

punctuation = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~،؟«؛«'

file1 = "stopwords.txt"
file2 = "golTest.txt"


witoutStops = []
corpuslines = []

def RemStopWords(file1, file2): 
    .
    .
    .  # do stuffs for omitting stop words and punctuations 

    #print (witoutStops)

def mostFreqWords():
    RemStopWords (file1, file2)
    with open ("TFFile.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        counter = Counter()
        for line in witoutStops:
            line = line.strip().split("\t")
            words = line[0].split()
            counter.update(words)
        top1000 = [word[0] for word in counter.most_common(1000)]
        return top1000

wordcount = {}
TFvalues = {}
def calculateValues():
    RemStopWords (file1, file2)
    for line in witoutStops:
        line = line.strip().split("\t")
        words = line[0].split()
        for word in words:
            if word not in wordcount:
                wordcount[word] = 1    # calculte the frequency of each word
            else:                      # in the file
                wordcount[word] += 1       
            value = wordcount.get(word, 1) # calculte Tf = log (1+ nij)
            result = math.log(1+value)
            TFvalues[word] = result

def TF():
    RemStopWords(file1, file2)
    mostfreq = mostFreqWords()
    calculateValues()
    for line in witoutStops:
        f =open ("abi.arff", "a", encoding = "utf-8") 
        line = line.split("\t")
        words = line[0].split()
        for word in words:
            for i in mostfreq:
                for k, v in TFvalues.items():
                    if word == k:
                        if any([i == word for word in words]):
                            value2 = TFvalues.get(word, 1)
                            f.write(str(value2,))
                        else:
                            f.write("0,")
            f.write(line[1])
TF()
```